# Sufficient condition for a solution to Hamburger moment problem

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, moments, hankel-matrices

Let $\{m_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of real numbers.
It is well known that there exist a positive Borel measure $\mu$  on the real line with moments given by $\{m_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ if and only if the Hankel matrix
    \begin{align}
A=(m_{i+j})_{i,j=0}^\infty,
\end{align}

is positive semi-definite.

In general the condition above condition can be difficult to verify.

My question: Is there a 'simpler' sufficient condition that can be checked?

Thanks.

Comment: Some literature which might be relevant: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123600936723  http://scholar.google.ch/scholar_url?url=http://www.emis.ams.org/journals/JIS/VOL4/LAYMAN/hankel.pdf&hl=de&sa=X&scisig=AAGBfm1Nmdud_7KTJIgNzO2vVGCdXmseDQ&nossl=1&oi=scholarr&ved=0ahUKEwjKnszbxPXRAhUC1BoKHY0bAsYQgAMIHSgBMAA